# Custom javascript partials instead of the default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to make my action render a java-script partial from a views/shared directory but haven't been successful so far.

```
respond_to do |format|
format.html //renders actionName.html.erb
format.js //renders actionName.js.erb
end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: assuming that your filename is _actionName.js.erb did you try using render :partial => "shared/actionName"

Comment: @Raghu That doesn't work. I couldn't make `render` to work with partials even in in the controller's own view directory.

Comment: have you checked the request format to ensure it's actually xhr?

Comment: are you sure that your filename has an underscore associated with it? like _actionName.js.erb ? Because I have seen a lot of folks missing that when trying to render partials

Comment: You're not really rendering a partial, like you do in a view, but actually rendering a file. So the underscore in front shouldn't be necessary for the js file. But if the js.erb file renders a file, then *that* is a partial and needs the underscore.

Comment: I have tried both with and without the underscore in the filename.

Comment: Use `binding.pry` or `debugger` one line before `respond_to` block, then execute `puts "it is xhr" if request.xhr?` in the server window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out:

```
format.js {render 'shared/actioanName.js'}
```

or

```
format.js {render :partial=> 'shared/actionName.js'}
```

In either cases you do have to add ".js" in the render statement.

You'll only need to prefix the latter's filename with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
format.js {render(:partial => 'shared/actionName')}
```